# Boolean Logic for Floats

Tags: logic, combinatorics, arithmetic

I would like to know whether a theory exists which generalizes boolean logic to floats.

Specifically, assume that instead of booleans 1 and 0, I have True/False *tendencies*, such as 0.9, where 0.1. Here, 1.0 would mean completely true, and 0.0 completely false.

Boolean logic:

```
0 && 1 # == 0
0 || 1 # == 1
```

It should be possible to have an equivalent for floats:

```
1. && 0.9 # == 0.9, because 1. * 0.9 = 0.9
1. || 0.9 # == 1., because 1 + 0.9 - 1. * 0.9 = 1.
```

Is there a theory for this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "[...], because $1\times 0.9=0.9$"? Does it imply a kind of probabilistic interpretation of the truth value? Like, two independent events of probability $p$ and $q$ respectively will both happen with probability $p\times q$?

Comment: @DatoClement exactly, "probabilistic interpretation" is a good formulation. I called it "tendency" in the question, which was less on point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you look up 'Fuzzy Logic'.

Comment: Short answer, but fair enough: It appears to be what I was looking for.